# How to match a property of an object to a property of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays of objects, `hList` and `sList`. I am trying to give each object in`sList` a property that matches an `hList.ID`, if one exists and is not already set. Im kind of tangled in the logic though, can someone help me out?

```
  var sList=[{name:"s1",id:"a"},{name: "s2",id:"b"},{name: "s3",id:"c"},{name: "s4",id:"d"}];
  var hList=[{name: "h1",id:"x"},{name: "h2",id:"y"},{name: "h3",id:"z"}];
```

so far I have:

```
try{    
  for(i in sList)
  {
    var s=sList[i];
    //find hList object that matches sList.id value
    var h=_.filter(hList.id,function(i){return(i==s.hID)});
    //if no hList.id match the sList.hID

    //find hList object that doesnt match any 

    //set the source id to the hList object id 

  }

}catch(err){console.log("err: ",err);}
```

GOAL: (only one `hList.id` can match an `sList.hID`. If an `hList.id` doesnt exist the `sList.hID` should be undefined.)

```
var sList=[{name:"s1",id:"a",hID:"x"},{name: "s2",id:"b",hID="y"},{name: "s3",id:"c",hID="z"},{name: "s4",id:"d",hID=undefined}]; //goal: set sList.hID to match an hList.id
var hList=[{name: "h1",id:"x"},{name: "h2",id:"y"},{name: "h3",id:"z"}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sList=[{name:"s1",id:"a"},{name: "s2",id:"b"},{name: "s3",id:"c"},{name: "s4",id:"d"}];
var hList=[{name: "h1",id:"x"},{name: "h2",id:"y"},{name: "h3",id:"z"}];
  
  
sList = sList.map((item, index) => {
  item.hId = hList[index] ? hList[index].id : undefined;
  return item
})

console.log(sList);
```

Comment: That worked great, Im going to have to read up on the`map` function. Thanks!